# Why use lambda instead of pattern matching?

Tags: parsing, haskell, lambda

I am watching a tutorial on parsers in haskell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FGThag0Fqs. The lecture starts with defining some really basic parsers. These are to be used together to create more complicated parsers later. One of the basic parsers is *item*. This is used to extract a character from the string we are parsing.

All parsers have the following type:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

The parser *item* is defined like this:

```
item :: Parser Char                                                             
item = \inp -> case inp of                                                      
                    [] -> []                                                
                    (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]
```

I am not so used to this syntax, so it looks strange to me. I would have written it:

```
item' :: Parser Char                                                            
item' [] = []                                                                   
item' (x:xs) = [(x,xs)]
```

Testing it in ghci indicates that they are equal:

```
*Main> item ""
[]
*Main> item "abc"
[('a',"bc")]
*Main> item' ""
[]
*Main> item' "abc"
[('a',"bc")]
```

The lecturer makes a short comment about thinking it looks clearer, but I disagree. So my questions are:

Are they indeed completely identical?
Why is the lambda version clearer?

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this comes from the common practice of writing

```
f :: Type1 -> ... -> Typen -> Result
f x1 ... xn = someResult
```

where we have exactly `n` function arrows in the type, and exactly `n` arguments in the left hand side of the equation. This makes it easy to relate types and formal parameters.

If `Result` is a type alias for a function, then we may write

```
f :: Type1 -> ... -> Typen -> Result
f x1 ... xn y = something
```

or

```
f :: Type1 -> ... -> Typen -> Result
f x1 ... xn = \y -> something
```

The latter follows the convention above: `n` arrows, `n` variables in the left hand side. Also, on the right hand side we have something of type `Result`, making it easier to spot. The former instead does not, and one might miss the extra argument when reading the code quickly.

Further, this style makes it easy to convert `Result` to a newtype instead of a type alias:

```
newtype Result = R (... -> ...)

f :: Type1 -> ... -> Typen -> Result
f x1 ... xn = R $ \y -> something
```

The posted `item :: Parser Char` code is an instance of this style when `n=0`.

Comment: I'm in full agreement on the newtype thing. You're going to want your parser to be a Functor and Applicative at least, and so you'll need the newtype, so making it ready for that with minimal editing is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

Why you should avoid equational function definitions (by Roman Cheplyaka):
http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-05-09-clauses

Major Points from the above link:

- DRY: Function and argument names are repeated --> harder to refactor
- Clearer shows which arguments the function decides upon
- Easy to add pragmas (e.g. for profiling)
- Syntactically closer to lower level code

This doesn't explain the lambda though..

Comment: @bheklilr i added a list

Answer (score 3):

I think they are absolutely equal. The lambda-style definition puts a name `item` to an anonymous lambda function which does pattern matching inside. The pattern-matching-style definition defines it directly. But in the end both are functions that do pattern matching. I think it's a matter of personal taste.

<strike>Also, the lambda-style definition could be considered to be in [pointfree](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style, i.e. a function defined without explicitly writing down its arguments</strike> actually it is not very much pointfree since the argument is still written (but in a different place), but in this case you don't get anything with this.

Here is another possible definion, somewhere in between of those two:

```
item :: Parser Char
item inp = case inp of
                [] -> []
                (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]
```

It's essentially identical to the lambda-style, but not pointfree.

Comment: It's not pointfree at all. In `\y -> ...`, the argument named `y` is the "point". Just because it's not on the left side of the `=` doesn't make this definition point-free.

Comment: @amalloy You're probably right (I'm editing my answer right now). But it's more pointfree than the direct definition, isn't it? :)